# node-windows not installing as windows service

Tags: node.js

We are trying to install the Node JS app as service in one of the server but when we run below script, it does not create the windows service. However, we were able to create windows service in another server using same script.

```
var Service = require('node-windows').Service;
console.log(" entered ");
// Create a new service object
var svc = new Service({
  name:'NodeJS App New',
  description: 'Node JS Application which converts Html String to PDF',
  script: 'S:\\HtmlToPdf\\MainApp.js',
  wait: 2,
  grow: .5
});
console.log(" entered 2 ");


console.log(" entered 3");
// Listen for the "install" event, which indicates the
// process is available as a service.
svc.on('install',function(){
console.log(" entered install ");
  svc.start();
});

svc.install();
console.log(" completed ");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working after removing the space in service name as below

```
name:'NodeJSAppNew',
```